# Manga about a noble girl who's banished by her parents and school, then later dies, goes back in time, and experiences similar events again

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, reincarnation

There's this manga I read a while ago. It's about a noble girl (villainess). She gets banished from school and her parents kick her out, and then she gets picked up by a merchant envoy.

Fast-forward, she dies (?), goes back in time to her banishment, goes through it all again, except this time she misses the envoy and becomes a herbalist or something.

This happens a few times and she becomes a maid and a knight; other things too (maybe). She dies one more time, and this time a duke or prince sees her and falls in love (?).

That's all I can really remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like ***[7th Time Loop: The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=174618)***.

From MangaUpdates:

> Rishe, the daughter of a duke, is stuck in a time loop that begins at the moment her engagement is annulled and ends with her early demise at the age of 20. She has now begun her seventh loop.
>
> In her past do-overs, Rishe experienced various occupations, including being a merchant, a pharmacist, and a knight. But this time around, she simply wishes to live a long and leisurely life!
>
> That was the plan, only for it to be derailed by an unprecedented marriage proposal from her killer in the previous loop, the neighbouring country's Crown Prince—?!

The protagonist, Rishe Irmgard Vuetzner, is stuck in a time loop, and is now beginning her seventh loop.

Each loop begins when she's fifteen years old, and ends when she dies five years later of various causes. At the beginning of each loop, her fiancée also abruptly breaks off his engagement with her, and her family kicks her out onto the streets, leaving her to fend for herself.

In her first loop, she encountered a peddler and his crew shortly after being made homeless, and served as an apprentice with them for a while, until she'd learned old enough to make a living on her own. However, she was eventually dragged into a war, and wound up dead.

In her second loop, she went to find the peddler again, but missed him, and ended up becoming a herbalist instead. In a subsequent life, she became a handmaiden, and in her sixth life, she masqueraded as a boy and became a knight, who died on the battlefield.

In her seventh life, she meets Emperor Arnold Hyne, the man who killed her in her sixth life. This time though, she isn't masquerading as a boy when they meet, and in a turnabout of events, he falls in love with her and asks her to marry him.

[image]

[image]